# Select certain elements from a vector and create a new vector with those elements in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector 'Y' which looks something like this:

```
[1 1 1 0 1 2 2 2 2]
```

I use the `Y(Y>1)` command to get all elements greater than 1, in this case, all `elements = 2`. How do I then create a new vector based off all the elements that the `Y(Y>1)` command gave me?
So I'd like to end up with

```
 X = [2 2 2 2]
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You had it there -`X = Y(Y>1)`

Answer (score 0):

You did answer your own question by `Y(Y>1)` :

```
>> y = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2]
y =
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     2     2     2     2     2
>> x=y(y>1)
x =
     2     2     2     2     2
```

because `(y>1)` returns a array of logical values with the size of `y` containing the result of the given check.

```
>> (y>1)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
```

you can then use this array to address data in your data array, all points where the logical array is 1 will be returned